# How To: create a second level of security in qr code

Tags: security, qr-code

QR code generally can be read by any QR code reader.
Is there any possibility of doing so ?
A qr code with two levels public and private..
the public level can be read by any normal qr code reader
private level with a private message can be read only by specific reading application..

Comment: Use your own encoding scheme or just encrypt the data and decrypt it with your own application

Comment: Thanks i was seaching on this and found a recent IEEE paper related to this.Two Level QR Code for Private Message sharing